# grep using regular expression "and"

Tags: regex, grep

How could I to filter out the line contains both `canvasbench` and `tracing_mark_write` like following sentence shown?

```
 canvasbench-16333 [003] ...1 87432.398788: tracing_mark_write: B|16333|performTraversals\n\
```

Comment: Will `canvasbench` always be at the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no AND operator in grep. But, you can simulate AND using grep -E option.

```
grep -E 'canvasbench.*tracing_mark_write|tracing_mark_write.*canvasbench' filename
```

And alternatively, you can use multiple grep command separated by pipe to simulate AND.

`grep -E 'canvasbench' filename | grep -E 'tracing_mark_write'`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use sed:

```
sed -n '/canvasbench/{/tracing_mark_write/p}' input
```

which tries to match tracing_mark_write on lines matching canvasbench and prints lines matching both.